# how to fix next.js 14 development environment slow compilation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, next.js

I am working on the Typescript - Next.js 14 Application.
My problem is that the development environment takes time to compilation. Sometimes it's nearly 60 seconds.

how can I fix this problem and fast the app compilation?